# Rails4 custom view routing with ID query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am attempting to create a second "show" view in my controller. I have added the following to my controller for the initial show view:

```
def show
  Sample.find(:id)
end
```

This works just fine in fact it can also work as:

```
def show
end
```

Now I am attempting to create a new view which we can call 'custom_show_view.html.erb'

I add it to the controller as:

```
def custom_show_view
  Sample.find(:id)
end
```

However when I try to call it I acquire an error with the URI (http://localhost/samples/custom_show_view/4) where `4` is the query for the active record id.

In my routes I added:

```
resources :samples do
  collection do
    get :custom_show_view
  end
end
```

But it only allows for a get of the page without the ID variable. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection` is for index views without an :id.  Use `member` if you need to show a specific record:

```
resources :samples do
  member do
    get :custom_show_view
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked well, thank you for a prompt response reading more on the routes differences.